How does spousal immigration sponsorship work if the immigrating spouse can work remotely?
I'm looking at the income requirements for bringing a foreign spouse to the US, and I understand it's meant to ensure the immigrant doesn't become a burden on the state.  Does this income requirement still apply even if the immigrant could support themselves?  Like they already have a job that they can continue doing even if they immigrate?

Where are you trying to bring your foreign spouse from?

@HelloDarkWorld I'm not, I was just talking about the system with someone who immigrated here that way and this question came up.

The intending immigrant's employment or income does not change the requirement for the petitioner of a family-based immigration case to sign an I-864 Affidavit of Support. However, the intending immigrant's income can be counted as part of the petitioner's household income in certain circumstances (so that, even if the petitioner has little or no income, their household income may still be sufficient for the I-864, after adding the intending immigrant's income). See I-864 instructions, page 12:

What if I Cannot Meet the Income Requirements?
If your income alone is not sufficient to meet the requirement for
your household size, the intending immigrant will be ineligible for an
immigrant visa or adjustment of status, unless the requirement can be
met using any combination of the following:
[...]

Income from the intending immigrant, if that income will continue from the same source after immigration, and if the intending immigrant
is currently living in your residence. If the intending immigrant is
your spouse, his or her income can be counted regardless of current
residence, but it must continue from the same source after he or she
becomes a lawful permanent resident;


In order for the intending immigrant's income to be counted, it must "continue from the same source after immigration". I am not sure whether the officer will consider this to have been met by an intending immigrant working outside the US, who will "work remotely" from the US after immigrating. You would probably need confirmation from the company that they are able to support such an arrangement, including the ability to withhold and pay applicable US taxes as the employer of someone working in the US.
(There are also some cases where an I-864 is not required. For example, if the intending immigrant can be credited with 40 quarters of Social Security credits, they can file I-864W instead. You can be credited with at most 4 credits per year, so this normally requires 10 years of working in the US. However, credits earned by the spouse during the period of marriage also count.)

No, the sponsor income requirement has nothing to do with the spouse's earning potential. The affidavit of support is a contract between the sponsor and the US government. See 8 USC 1183a.
